# transfer of patents

Tags: law

What happens if *Company A* has acquired *Company B*, during which the patents need to be assigned from *Company A* to *Company B*. The signature for this assignment for both the companies has been done by the same person.

What are the laws governing this?

Comment: @Pushpak They are not looking to license the technology. They want to transfer ownership of the patents.

Comment: @Avi its unclear what you are asking, company A aquired B and then A assigns patents to B? B is now currently A what is the benefit here?

Answer (score 1):

The person who provided both signatures has a Conflict of Interest. I have witnessed one case where the rights to two patents were signed from a university to a company, where the inventor was a member of both organizations and would normally have signing power at the company. The way this was resolved was that the company designated a different signing authority for their side of the transaction. This was, of course, in addition to a Conflict of Interest being declared and the mutually-amenable resolution of the conflict being agreed upon in advance of the transfer.

Answer (score -1):

You can record the document listing the patents as property bought by the new company... (redact anything like a price that you wouldn't want shown)